# Type problem when assigning a value to an object

Tags: typescript

I have something like the following code:

```
type ModelValues = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

type ModelKey = keyof ModelValues;

const x: Partial<ModelValues> = {
  a: 42,
};

const y: ModelValues = {
  a: 7,
  b: 'a',
};

(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
  y[key] += x[key];
});
```

In the left side of the assignment in the next-to-last line, I get the message `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ModelValues'`.

`key` seems to be interpreted as a string, though the `Object.keys` are explicitly casted as of type `ModelKey`.

When I give the `ModelKey` type to the `key` variable itself, it still doesn't work, but the error message is instead `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

Any ideas why this happens and what I should do to fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a problem that the properties of the object are of different types. If I use only properties of type `number`, it almost works. I just need another type cast to make sure that `x[key]` is actually a number, because x is only `Partial<ModelValues>`.
Still, I want to use properties of different types (though I don't actually add strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problematic case of the typescript compiler. This issue is called "correlated unions". See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more.

From the issue:

> For now the only workarounds are type assertions (which are not safe) or to walk the compiler manually through the different constituents of the union type via type guards (which is repetitive and brittle).

I will choose the safe option.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59432276/9483495

> The problem here is that if you're assigning a value to an arbitrary key, then that value must have a type which is assignable to every key you might be assigning it to. That means the value's type has to be string & number in order to be assignable to both string and number property types. The intersection string & number is never.

This is what I would do:

#### Initial State:

```
(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
    y[key] += x[key];
});
```

#### 1. Remove ModelKey assertion

In runtime x can include every key, so let's remove the type assertion to be safer:

```
Object.keys(x).forEach((key) => { // key: string
    y[key] += x[key];
});
```

#### 2. Add non-null assertion

We know that key is in x since we iterate over its keys. So we can add non-null assertion to x[key]:

```
Object.keys(x).forEach((key) => { // key: string
    y[key] += x[key]!;
});
```

#### 3. Use safe approach to check keys names

Check every possible keys to behave different on each of them

```
type ModelValues = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
};

type ModelKey = keyof ModelValues;

const x: Partial<ModelValues> = {
    a: 42,
};

const y: ModelValues = {
    a: 7,
    b: "2"
};

Object.keys(x).forEach(key => {
    if(key === 'a'){
        y[key] += x[key]!;
    } else if(key === 'b'){
        y[key] += x[key]!;
    } else {
       // handle other keys here, they can exist in the runtime
    }
});
```

#### Alternative

Other option would be to turn off type checking via type assertion:

```
(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
    (y[key] as any) += x[key];
});
```

### Edit:

#### Casting to other types than any

#### 1. number

Note that you need to cast x[key] here too, otherwise x[key] is `string | number`, y[key] is `number`; the addition can be a `string` which is not a `number`. Note that, `number + undefined` is still a number(NaN) but the problematic part is `number + string`

```
(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
    (y[key] as number) += (x[key] as number);
});
```

#### 2. string

We tell compiler that y[key] will be `string`. y[key] + x[key] will still be a `string`, since all

1. string + `number`
2. string + `string`
3. string + `undefined`

are a string. So no error with this:

```
(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
    (y[key] as string) += x[key];
});
```

Comment: I like your "safe approach", thanks! However, isn't there a more DRY solution for assignment without simply casting to `any`?

Comment: Actually, your alternative solution pointed me in the right direction. But instead of casting `y[key]` to `any` (which I wouldn't like), it does also work when casted to `string` - though I don't really understand why. `number` instead, doesn't. Even omitting the non-null assertion works both, when compiling without warning, and in runtime when adding numbers and concatenating strings.
If you would add this to your solution, I would mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Edited the answer. Non-null assertion works, I explained it in string part. Note that, for the number case number + undefined is still a number(NaN) but the problematic part is number + string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keys of object `y` can be either numbers or strings. This is causing a conflict, because TypeScript does not know if the number of x will be added to a string or to a number.

The solution is to convert both to strings, or both to numbers, depending on the result you want to achieve.

I tested this code in the official TypeScript Playground and it has no errors:

```
type ModelValues = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
};

type ModelKey = keyof ModelValues;

const x: Partial<ModelValues> = {
  a: 42,
};

const y: ModelValues = {
  a: 7,
  b: 'a',
};

(Object.keys(x) as ModelKey[]).forEach((key) => {
  y[key] == y[key].toString() + x[key]; // convert the key of y to a string.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Though it solves the compiler warning, I do not want to use string concatenating in every case, but to add numerically, if the key is of type `number`